# Load data EXC BAD ACCESS (only device)

Tags: ios, iphone, save, load, exc-bad-access

When my custom data is loading on iPhone (3G, with 3.1) I get Exc Bad Access
in this line:

```
NSMutableArray* dataArr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathGG]; //=EXC BAD ACCESS
```

**On Ipad, and on simulator work**

I saving data in simulator (to documentsDirectory path), then replace data to project, and load from [NSBundle mainBundle]

In array I use NSValue for store CGPoint.

Full source:

```
-(void) SaveData:(NSMutableArray*)dataLevel {
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"data.dat";
NSString* pathGG = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]; // retain];

BOOL isWrite = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dataLevel toFile:pathGG];

if(isWrite) NSLog(@"YES");  
else  NSLog(@"!!!");
}

+(NSMutableArray*) LoadData  {
NSString* fileName = @"data.dat"; 
NSString* pathGG =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"dat"]; // retain];
NSMutableArray* dataA = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathGG];  //EXC BAD ACCESS

return dataA;
}
```

If I am using follow way(saving/loading same method), I get EXC BAD ACCESS too:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver* decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSArray* dataArr = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dataLevel"]; //EXC BAD ACCESS
```

Comment: Debug an check if any of those variables/pointers are NIL

Comment: In save method all variable not nil. In load method pathGG is not nil, (by the way, if file not found, I don't get EXC BAD ACCESS). I noted that, when I debug in Simulator, value of dataArr in first seconds "Invalid sum", but after some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString* pathGG = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] retain];
```

Then when you are finished with it:

```
[pathGG release]
```

Comment: I saving data in simulator (to documentsDirectory path), then replace data to project, and load from [NSBundle mainBundle] on Iphone.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Instead of store `CGPoint` in `NSValue`, use `CGPointFromString`(after `NSStringFromCGPoint`), and then add string to array.

```
NSString* positionStr = NSStringFromCGPoint(someCGPoint); 
[someArray addObject:position];
// Now, saving array to file
...
```

//After loading array from file

```
CGPoint positon = CGPointFromString([someArr objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: This does not answer your question.